# Difference between "ну" and "значит"

Tags: узус

What is the difference between "ну" and "значит" in usage? Can they be used interchangeably? I believe they both mean something similar to "so" or "well" in English

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the following explanation, translations are not at all word by word translations, and each translation relies on the context of the discussion used in the answer.

*"Значит"* translates to *"means"*.
It is used however in some cases as a start of a told explanation, like this:

> Значит так: я пойду за детьми а ты жди мастера

which would translate roughly to:

> Ok, so I will pick up the kids and you wait for the repair man.

Sometimes, similarly, the same word can be used to ask for a confirmation on the explanation:

> Значит я пойду за детьми?
>
> So, I will pick up the kids?

Indeed, the usage of the word *"значит"* does in some cases coincide with the english *"so"*. But when you try to replace *"well"* in the same sentences, it won't work. *"so"* gives a command tone to the sentence, while *"well"* is kind of unsure.

> well, maybe you will go to pick up the kids and I'll wait home?

this does translate to something like this:

> ну может ты пойдёшь за детьми и я подожду дома?

If you substitute the word, you'd have to change the tone of the sentence as well.

Another case of *"ну"* is for answering the same kind of question:

> ну ладно, поеду
>
> well OK, I'll do it

or answering a stupid question:

> ну используй мозги, придёшь к ответу
>
> well, use your brains, and you'll come to the answer

As you can see, in both languages, the given examples would not support word substitution without slightly changing the meaning.

Comment: Great explanation. One thing though: "well" is much more decisive than "so." In fact it's usually used by the person who comes up with a plan where there is none. "Well (since nobody else has a game plan) I'll pick up the kids and you wait for the plumber." On the other hand, "so" shows trepidation and seeks confirmation: So I'll pick up the kids and you'll wait here (is that the idea?). Again thanks for clearing up the Russian usage of ну анд значит!

Comment: Interestingly enough, in the States we use "well" authoritatively, as I described above, whereas in Britain they tend to use "right" in the same situation.

Comment: Note: "_Значит так_, ..." sounds like an order. "Значит так, делай что я говорю и не спорь".

Comment: At first I didn't understand the question, but then it got me thinking. The answer is just a result of me thinking in written form. I guess "so" relates to an explanation. Either demanding or giving one. The same with the russian word "значит".
I know both languages intuitively more than knowing each word's objective usage cases, and I gave it my best shot.

Answer (score 1):

In its usage as a filler word, *значит* generally signifies that the speaker is pursuing a particular train of thought, i.e. that they're on track and know what they're going to say next, even if they have a momentary difficulty. *Ну*, on the other hand, is largely the opposite, an expression of looking for a thread to follow. You can think of *значит* as reflecting the mental equivalent of consulting one's notes, whereas *ну* is like flipping through the notebook to find the right page.